# Is there a way to process new Gmail emails before theit hit the inbox?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

Like the title says, is there a way, using the Gmail API, to process emails *before* they hit the inbox? The idea is to automatically filter out some of the less important ones under labels and mark them as archived. I'd like those emails not to show up in the inbox at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out how to do it. The way to make sure unprocessed emails never hit the inbox is to create a filter that archives all new emails and gives them a label, eg "unprocessed". Then use the API and pub/sub to actually process emails.

To create filters through the API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings

Answer (score 0):

### You can't directly "process" the message before it's in the inbox

It's possible to do after a message is in the inbox by using [Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push), keep in mind it has its [limitations](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#limitations) though.

After all of that you can filter based on your needs (add labels) and make use of `pull()` and `acknowledge()` methods in order to respond notifications.

### Reference

[Gmail API > Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)

[Pub/Sub > pull](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull)

[Pub/Sub > acknowledge](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/acknowledge)